Plot X and Y chart with third column as legend for each point in Excel or Google Sheets
I am having difficulty understanding why it is so difficult to do something so simple in R or Python in Excel or Google Sheets.
I want to plot Status1 versus Status2 in a simple X and Y plot. However, I cannot add "Name" as a legend for each point.
It seems the concept of legend for a point does not exist. Or very hard to find.
In this example, I want the X-axis to be Status 1 and the Y-axis to be Status 2. For each point, I want to see the "Name" of the point.
I have a sample data:



Name
Status1
Status2




Bla
1
2


Bla2
2
3


Bla3
3
5




in google sheets try like this:

